# How to deal with relational data in Solr

Tags: solr, search-engine, solrnet, faceted-search, facet

We're right now planning to roll out Solr search for e-commerce site with faceted catalog navigation.

We are having a little complex data schema for product and its specification attribute which are dynamic.

We are certainly not able to understand how to map this data into the Solr? Does we need to have two indexes, one for product index and another for specification attribute that is mapped with product or just single schema.

But how, any example will be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently you cannot join across multiple solr indexes.  There is going to be [Join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) functionality in Solr 4.0.  However, this will enable joining documents within an individual index.

Normalized database schema must be flattened before indexing it in Solr.  This is actually where you will gain most run time performance gain, as joins in a database are expensive.

Duplication of some of the columns across Products and Specifications is ok.  May be if you can describe the individual attributes and cardinality, I could opine further.

My background is, I have indexed a heavily normalized database schema into 3 solr indexes. I used a cardinality test, and search usecases to narrow down this split.  For instance, I had Customer agreements in one index, agent agreements in another, and relationships between customers and agents in another.  I landed on the fewest indexes I could get to.  A service tier integrates the three indexes.  Creating a single index here would have made it too huge and complex to maintain.

One of the other approaches you can try is search solr, and enrich individual docs by a database dip.  This comes with some cost, but if you already resolved primary keys in the solr search, these lookups will not be that expensive.

Comment: Historically Solr pre-releases have been used in production(us included).  Of course it depends on the company's appetite for dealing with issues, feature set needed, and availability of programmers who can fix solr bugs etc.